# How to change neovim PATH during installation proccess

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to install neovim and in the instructions, it says to add `C:\Program Files\nvim\bin` to my PATH but I don't know how. Where do I change it and how?

Sidenote: I wasn't even able to change my vim $PATH if that is what it is talking about.

Comment: Did you try searching for "update windows path"?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that it was the windows path. I did `echo %path% and was able to look at my PATH. All I have to do is figure out how to change it.

Comment: Just figured it out. Thank you so much! :D